# How to strip punctuation of at the beginning and the end of string column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which some rows have unecessary punctuations like , ? . etc in the beginning and the end of it string type columns, how can strip those punctuation use Pandas? Thanks.

```
id   price    fruits
01     1       .apple
02     2       ,apple, banana?
03     3       ?orange?
```

It should be like this

```
id   price    fruits
01     1       apple
02     2       apple, banana
03     3       orange
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) with `punctuation`:

```
import string
df['fruits'] = df['fruits'].str.strip(string.punctuation)
print (df)
   id  price         fruits
0   1      1          apple
1   2      2  apple, banana
2   3      3         orange

print (string.punctuation)
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

EDIT:

For custom `punctuation` is possible use string, only necessary escape `"` if value for check:

```
df['fruits'] = df['fruits'].str.strip(",\"?'.")
print (df)

   id  price         fruits
0   1      1          apple
1   2      2  apple, banana
2   3      3         orange
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why it doesn't remove comma in second row? By the way, if it's not English punctuation, will it work out?

Comment: @ahbon - `strip` working for test each character form start ane end, so all `punctuation` betwen some another strings is not removed.. for second question give me a sec

Comment: sorry i have another question, what if i want only want remove the punctuation in the beginning of string? and in the end?

Comment: Then use [`lstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html) or [`rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html)